# Azure Functions .Net 5 Is it possible to bind CosmosInput to parameters in HttpRequestData?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-5, c#-9.0

Actually the title is self-descriptive. I have an azure function on .Net5 with http trigger which has to send back results received by running . Is it possible (even some weird hacky way would work) to pass parameters coming in HttpRequestData to CosmosInput query? For certain reasons I want to go with azure functions functionality and don't want to implement full-fledged Cosmos routine inside function.

Comment: i believe here you might find examples you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=csharp#http-trigger-look-up-id-from-query-string-c

Comment: @deezg, missed that, thanks. The only problem is that I need to pass array of possible ids and not sure how to implement this. For just one id value I could use route.

Comment: i believe there is an example for it with using route data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=csharp#http-trigger-look-up-id-from-route-data-using-sqlquery

Comment: What specific data from HttpRequestData are you trying to merge with cosmos input ? Can you share some relevant code and your expected behavior ?